# What does this ls command do?

Tags: terminal, ls, command

what does this command do if it was executed in my current working directory that has files in it?

ls 2> result

I think whatever ls writes will be redirected to the result file?

Is that correct and will it redirect everything for stderr and stdout? Or only stderr?

Comment: Check the accepted answer for this question: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 0):

`ls` command does listing of given directory. Only `ls` lists current directory's contents. `>` and `2>` are IO Redirection tools. `>` is used to redirect `stdout` - standard output. `2>` is for `stderr` - standard error. So:

```
user@linux:~$ ls 2> result
```

will redirect errors of ls command to file named `result`. To redirect both (error and output), you need to use:

```
user@linux:~$ ls >>result 2>&1
```

It will redirect and append `stdout` and `stderr` to that file.

**Good luck!**